# How to create a dynamic button using dynamic data and get dynamic values on the button click in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Here i am getting  below Dynamic data from server

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "first_name": "Eve",
            "last_name": "Holt",
            "lat":"25.6599899",
            "lng":"45.3664646",
            "status":"0"

        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "first_name": "Charles",
            "last_name": "Morris",
            "lat":"25.99899",
            "lng":"45.4646",
             "status":"1"

        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "first_name": "Tracey",
            "last_name": "Ramos",
            "lat":"25.2339899",
            "lng":"45.56664646",
            "status":"1"

        }
    ]
}
```

Here how to create the Dynamic buttons based on the Status value suppose if status=1 value having 3 members then 3 buttons  have to be created with that particular names and ids and when the user clicks any button that particular of the person and name has to be displayed on alert

Comment: Have you tried writing any code yourself yet? (if not, you should try that first)

Comment: yeah im looping the data based on the condition and then i got only one confusion how can i get the   name, id ,status values in the button?

Comment: Please provide some code that shows the work that you've done so far and where you are struggling. Additionally, the details around what is being asked is vague without enough information to determine what is needed, which will most likely not solicit too much help right now.

Comment: As already stated, please show the code you've actually written. Also a **hint:** this is the basic use case for frameworks like Angular (see `ngFor`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As is understand like you need button for each status = 1 and on click need to display name of person.

**ts code**

Variable

```
public dynamicData = {
"data": [
  {
    "id": 4,
    "first_name": "Eve",
    "last_name": "Holt",
    "lat": "25.6599899",
    "lng": "45.3664646",
    "status": "0"

  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "first_name": "Charles",
    "last_name": "Morris",
    "lat": "25.99899",
    "lng": "45.4646",
    "status": "1"

  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "first_name": "Tracey",
    "last_name": "Ramos",
    "lat": "25.2339899",
    "lng": "45.56664646",
    "status": "1"

  }
]
};
```

Method

```
onButtonClick(data: any): void {
   alert(data.first_name + ' status is ' + data.status);
}
```

**HTML Code**

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let data of dynamicData.data">
     <button [id]="data.id" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onButtonClick(data)">
        {{data.first_name}}
     </button>
  </ng-container>
```

Comment: Yeah but suppose if have 5 persons with status=0 and 3, persons with status =1 then for 5person 5 buttons  with 5names on them and when I click on their individual name their individual name and I'd has to be displayed in alert and I have show all these in if else condition as both status 0,1,2 person count n buttons has to be displayed at a time

Comment: @TechieBoy i have revised my ans.

Comment: im able to dsiplay only one name even though i have more than 1